# How can I input a conditional argument type in python?

Tags: python

I am new to python. I want to input xx in line 4 as the type of argument (for example 'int' or 'str') for b in line 5 so that the argument b takes the type as inputted in xx. Which means the type of argument b should be user defined instead of specifying it in the code itself. I know that the written code below for line 4 and 5 are not correct.

```
def FindLength(arg):
    Length=len(arg)
    return Length
xx=input("type: ")
b=xx(input("Enter the argument: "))
if type(b)==int:
    print("Integer do not have length")
else:
    print("Length of the argument is",FindLength(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t need it to actually be a type, just compare it to a string:

```py
b=input("Enter the argument: ")
if b=="int":
    print("Integer do not have length")
else:
    print("Length of the argument is",FindLength(b))
```

If you do need actual types AND YOU TRUST THE USER look into `eval()`:

```py
b=eval(input("Enter the argument: "))
if b=="int":
    print("Integer do not have length")
else:
    print("Length of the argument is",FindLength(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` **always** return `str`

So actually you always can get length of any input

```py
a = input('> ')
print("length of a is ", len(a))
```

```
~ $ python script.py
> 123
length of a is  3
~ $ python script.py
> dfervf
length of a is  6
~ $ python script.py
> 1
length of a is  1
~ $ python script.py
> 0
length of a is  1
```

If you want to check is user insert number or string, you may use [isnumeric](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isnumeric.asp) or just catch exception when trying to cast to `int`

- isnumeric

```py
a = input('> ')

if a.isnumeric():
  a_int = int(a)
  ...
else:
  print(len(a))
```

- catch exception

```py
a = input('> ')

try:
  int(a)
except ValueError as e:
  print("a is string but not number")
```

- In other way you may catch exception when trying to get length

```py
a = 5

try:
  print("the length of a is ", len(a))
except TypeError as e:
  print("a has no len()")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although, instead of 'a_int' under isnumeric condition it should be only 'a'.

Comment: `instead of 'a_int' under isnumeric condition it should be only 'a'.` → up to you. I just tried to show that `a_int` is integer, but `a` is string

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the problem using the below code. It works fine for types such as 'int', 'float' and 'str' as well. However, more data types can be added by just extending the conditional blocks (try and except ValueError).

```
def FindLength(arg):
    Length=len(arg)
    return Length

a=input("Enter the argument: ")
try:
    b=int(a)
    print("Integer do not have length")
except ValueError:
    try:
        b=float(a)
        print("Float do not have length")
    except ValueError:
        print("Length of the argument is",FindLength(a))
```